# Cannot configure Jest for WebStorm/IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs, webstorm

I have installed Jest using npm :

```
npm i jest --save-dev
```

At the package level I also have a Jest config file: `jest.config.js` which is very simple and just contains :

```js
const config = {
    verbose: true,
};

module.exports = config;
```

However if I look at a test that I wrote, the `expect()` cannot be compiled :

[image]

On closer inspection **WebStorm/IntelliJ** thinks that `describe()` and `it()` belong to **mocha**, and not **jest**.

How do I point IntelliJ/WebStorm to jest and not to mocha? I can't seem to find anything in the settings.

Comment: you can try installing [`@types/jest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jest) as devDependency

Comment: tried that, but it didnt work. IJ still doesnt recognise "expect"